# What is "звор" in "встань з крутого звора"?

Tags: значення-слів

[From a song:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vyHrBI1hRac)

> На світанку чути сурми грають,
>   Кличуть нас Прабатьківські Боги.
>   З Ладоги до синього Дунаю,
>   Вже встають, єднаються полки.
>
> Приспів:
>   Встань із листя, встань з трави,
>   Встань **з крутого звора**!
>   Хоругва до хоругви!
>   Прапор до прапора!
>   Прапор до прапора!

I think that **звор** is the bank of a river. But I haven't found the word **звор** in the [словник](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk).

Comment: if I correctly deciphered [this](https://sjp.pwn.pl/doroszewski/zwor;5532234.html) article in polish, most likely ´звор´ is a very steep bank of a river in mountains

Comment: Про всьак зазначу, шчо польське _zwór_ сье не _зво́р_, јак може здати сьа, а _звур_, але сье подібна річ до нашого _звора_ — _звір_.

Comment: @follower та я ще й артикль забув :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [**ЗВІР²**, *зво́ру*, **ІЗВІ́Р**, *ізво́ру*](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=34920&page=1110), *ч.*, *діал*. Яр.
>
> *І тут, доки зір засягне, високі гірські шпилі, ліси, долини і звори* (І. Франко); *Вниз западалися боки гори у глибокі чорні ізвори, звідки родились холодні потоки, куди не ступала людська нога* (М. Коцюбинський); *Серце рвалося туди, до тих таємних гір, полонин далеких, незвіданих скель та ізворів* (Г. Хоткевич); *На крутому зворі горить дерев'яний міст* (В. Кучер); *Очі стали погано бачити, а воно ж кругом як не гори, то горби, як не звори, то байраки...* (І. Білик).

You did not find because base-word is *звір*, not *звор*. Do not forget (for check) about [a pare O–I](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par8).